# Datatemplate for combobox not switching selected value when binded with Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml

At runtime all the items are selected with the same item.

How can I make it so that it will all be binded to their respective Datacontext?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Source={StaticResource CalculationTypesLookUp}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="CalculationTypeDescription"
                      SelectedValuePath="Id"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding CalculationTypeId, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add *IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"* it will fix your issue.
By default it will be set to true IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
making all the datatemplate instances the same.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculationTypesLookUp}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="CalculationTypeDescription"
                          SelectedValuePath="Id"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding CalculationTypeId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"/>
```